# Shows by an example that a $\gamma$-hyperconnected space in topology may not be hyperconnected.

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space $(X,T)$ a subset A of X is said to be preopen if $A \subset int(cl(A))$ and $\gamma$-open if $A \cap B$ is preopen for every preopen set B in $X.$ $(X, T)$ is said to be hyperconnected if closure of any open set gives $X$ and $\gamma$-hyperconnected if $\gamma$-closure of each $\gamma$-open set gives $X$.

Comment: You should state your question the body. Also, how do you define $γ$-closure? Is it true that every open set is $γ$-open?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me tell you,  I tried to solve it further and I found an example.

Comment: You shouldn't have found an example. Since every open set is $γ$-open, every $γ$-hyperconnected space is hyperconnected, isn't it?

Comment: You are talking about topological space. In bitopology I found that example.

Comment: You didn't mention bitopology in the question. Also, if you have just two unrelated topologies, it is trivial. You should first pose the question correctly.

Comment: Ooo yeah. Thanks. By the way, in this question, is the converse part true?

Comment: No, it is not. If you take an indiscrete space, then every subset is preopen and so every subsets is $γ$-open.

Comment: Can you give me an example for the converse case, that is a hyperconnected topological space may not be a $\gamma$-hyperconnected topological space.

Comment: The example is just in the previous comment.

Comment: If we define $\gamma$-hyperconnected space as follows, then can you prove the given statement with the help an example:     \\ A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be $\gamma$-hyperconnected if closure of each $\gamma$-open set gives $X$.

Comment: Every indiscrete space is hyperconnected, but it is not $γ$-hyperconnected unless it's degenerate.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: If you don't know what is an indiscrete space you should have asked specifically about this. Otherwise, you should see that such space has only one nonempty open set, and so is hyperconnected. On the other hand, every nonempty set is dense, and so every set is preopen, and so every set is $γ$-open, and so if the space has at least two points, it is not $γ$-hyperconnected.

Comment: Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and  $\tau = \{\phi, X\}$. Then $\phi$ and $X$ are the only closed sets and every element in $PO(X)$ is $\gamma$-open set. Now if you take closure of any $\gamma$-open set, it will obviously give $X$. In this sense $(X, \tau)$ will be called $\gamma$-hyperconnected.

Comment: You shoudn't take the closure of a $γ$-open set, but the $γ$-closure.

Comment: So according to you the definition of $\gamma$-hyperconnected space should be as follows: A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be $\gamma$-hyperconnected if $cl_\gamma (A) =X, \forall \gamma$-open set $A$.

Comment: That's according to you, see the very end of your post.

Comment: And it makes sense – $τ$ being $γ$-hyperconnected is just a shortcut to saying that $γτ$ is hyperconnected (where $γτ$ denotes the induced collection of $γ$-open sets). The point of the counterexample is that when $τ$ is indiscrete, $γτ$ is discrete.

Comment: Sir, there is a great misunderstanding. I made a comment on 21st January where I defined $\gamma$-hyperconnected space differently. Again I am putting that definition: A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be $\gamma$-hyperconnected if $cl(A) = X, \forall \gamma$-open set A. The reason to define $\gamma$-hyperconnected space in that way is: The claim that "every $\gamma$-hyperconnected space becomes a hyperconnected space" stands true.

Comment: Considering the above definition of $\gamma$-hyperconnected space, I was searching for an example of such space which is hyperconnected but not $\gamma$-hyperconnected.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you have changed the definition in the comment. I was still referring to the original definition. I think $γ$-hyperconnected should still mean the original definition, and the implication is still true. Just the trivial counterexample is not valid for the modified definition. I'll summarize the situation in a proper answer.

Comment: I will wait for your positive reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize the picture. We start with some topology $T$ on a set $X$. The topology induces a finer family of all preopen sets, say $pT$. This in general does not have to be a topology. So we may fix this by introducing the collection of all $γ$-open sets – $γT$. It seems to me that $γT$ is a topology.

In general, we may say that a set $X$ is *$(T_1, T_2)$-hyperconnected* (where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are topologies on $X$) if for every nonempty sets $U ∈ T_1$, $V ∈ T_2$ we have $U ∩ V ≠ ∅$. This way,

- $(X, T)$ is *hyperconnected* if it is $(T, T)$-hyperconnected,

  $(X, T)$ is *$γ$-hyperconnected* if it is $(γT, γT)$-hyperconnected,

  and in the comments we have also considered the condition of being $(T, γT)$-hyperconnected.

Since we have $Τ ⊆ γT ⊆ pT$, we have also the implications $γ$-hyperconnected $\implies$ $(T, γT)$-hyperconnected $\implies$ hyperconnected.

If $T$ is indiscrete, then both $pT$ and $γT$ are discrete. This shows $(T, γT)$-hyperconnected $\not\Rightarrow$ $γ$-hyperconnected.

It turns out that $X$ is hyperconnected if and only if it is $(T, γT)$-hyperconnected. For every nonempty preopen set $A$ there is an open set $U$ such that $A ⊆ U$ and $A$ is dense in $U$. So if $X$ is hyperconnected, for every nonempty open set $V$ we have $U ∩ V ≠ ∅$, and so $A ∩ V ≠ ∅$ since $A$ is dense in $U$. That means $X$ is even $(T, pT)$-hyperconnected.

So it is really like this: $γ$-hyperconnected $\implies$ hyperconnected, and the indiscrete space is a counterexample for the other implication.